# what are the semantics of python multiprocessing. join with timeout. Why does it hang

Tags: python, multiprocessing, sympy

Newbie here in `Python` and `sympy`. I have simple question.

If I start a worker using multiprocessing, and give it some small timeout say 3 seconds, in the `join` call. What happens if the worker is busy itself, may be waiting for something to complete? what happens when the timeout expires and worker itself is waiting for `sympy`?

I found that if the worker calls `sympy` on a long computation, the join hangs waiting for the worker, much longer than the time out period.

Here is a MWE

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')

def worker(integrand,que):
    que.put(integrate(integrand, x))

if __name__ == '__main__':       
    que = Queue()
    result = "still waiting "

    #this first call works OK since it is easy integral
    #action_process = Process(target=worker,args=(cos(x),que))

    #this one hangs inside sympy since hard integral
    p = Process(target=worker,args=(1/(x**3+cos(x)),que))

    # start the process and wait for max of 3 seconds.
    p.start()   
    p.join(timeout=3)
    result=que.get()    
    print("result from worker is " + str(result))
    p.terminate()
```

**Question:** Is it possible to force the worker to terminate at the timeout? Is there another option to use to do that? Am I doing something wrong in the above?

If not possible to force timeout at join, then what is the meaning of join() after n seconds, if the worker can't join?

Only reason I am trying the above is to find a way to timeout on long computation in `sympy`, since I am on windows and timers and alarms do not work on windows, so I thought to try multiprocessing with timeout, but it does not seem to do what I want and hence this will not be any use for what I want.

ps. if you run the above, worker will hang inside `sympy` for long time, may be 10 minutes or more, and might have to kill it manually.

The above is on windows. But I also tried in on Linux, and it also hangs.

Anacode 4.3.1, Python 3.6

**Update**

Thanks to hint in answer, this below seems to work now

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')

def worker(integrand,que):
    que.put(integrate(integrand, x))

if __name__ == '__main__':       
    que = Queue()
    result = "timed out "

    #this one hangs inside sympy since hard integral
    p = Process(target=worker,args=(1/(x**3+cos(x)),que))

    # start the process and wait for max of 3 seconds.
    p.start()   
    p.join(timeout=3)

    try:
       result=que.get(block=False)    
    except:
       print("timed out on que.get()")
       pass

    print("result from worker is " + str(result))
    p.terminate()
```

I still need to test it more to make sure the worker process() does get killed by terminate as I do not want to have zombie workers around.

Comment: Are you sure that this function has an elementary integral?

Comment: @Anis This one does not. But this is really beside the point. I just needed to set a timeout  on sympy calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code never reaches the `print` "in time" is because it doesn't get beyond the `result=que.get()`. You specified a timeout for `p.join` which makes the calling process resume after the specified timeout. However [`que.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get) is also blocking and therefore waits until an item has been put in the queue. You can specify a timeout here as well: `que.get(timeout=...)` or simply turn off blocking: `que.get(block=False)`. In any case, if no item is available in the queue, it will raise a [`queue.Empty`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Empty) exception.

However the documentation contains [several](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) about terminating a process that holds a (shared) reference to a queue. The [Programming Guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) seem to contain a solution for that case and also warn of possible deadlocks (see "Joining processes that use queues").

Comment: thanks. I added updated code using `que.get(block=False)` it seems to work OK so far. But I am not sure if I still need to check for something else or not.